# css !important override/change margin

Tags: css

Trying to make a change in my stylesheet and having a bit of a problem changing the margin on this.
I need to edit the Bottom Margin to a number percent.

```
{
position: relative !important;
display: block !important;
margin: 1% auto !important;
width: 100% !important;
top: auto !important;
right: auto !important;
bottom: auto !important;
left: auto !important;
}
```

what would be the correct way?

Comment: Show complete relevant code.

Comment: Just add your percentage into the margin.  margin: 1% auto (your %) !important;

Comment: You should not need all those `!important` tags, it's bad practice to use them if not absolutely necessary. You can just put `margin-bottom: x% !important;` under your margin and it will overwrite the `auto` value above it.

Comment: Thank you. This is just what I wanted. I tried editing just bottom but it wasnt working. Tried what you suggested and perfect. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This should work, where x is the percentage you want:

```
{
position: relative !important;
display: block !important;
margin: 1% auto x% !important;
width: 100% !important;
top: auto !important;
right: auto !important;
bottom: auto !important;
left: auto !important;
}
```